# how about android interval

Tags: android, multithreading, intervals

i did wifi scanning for android, but now i want this wifi scanning run at set interval period, how this can be done, can any provide any snippets,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found answer my question, just simple
declare below before onCreate

```
TimerTask scanTask;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer t = new Timer();
```

write below on onCreate

```
scanTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        startScanning();  //here where u want to call the method
                    }
           });
    }};
t.schedule(scanTask, 300, 5000);  // here is t.schedule( , delay, period);
```

thats it

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Timer` 
 http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Create a background service which holds the Timer, and call `scheduleAtFixedRate`